# Tool/Library for finding multiple assigned color profiles of an image other than photoshop?

Tags: colors, image-formats, color-profile

I read [here](http://blog.iso50.com/2009/08/18/color-management-a-field-guide/) that when sending an image for print it can have multiple color profiles assigned to it, which will cause a difference in color between what is displayed on your monitor and what is printed on your printer.

I was wondering if there were any tools and or libraries that can detect what "stacked" color profiles have been assigned to the image.

Comment: Found this: http://regex.info/exif.cgi ...

Comment: Aaaaaand EXIF data is not a color profile. You should probably read this if you really want to understand how profiles work. http://bit.ly/4Jvq7B

Comment: @NSD I read of that web tool here: http://regex.info/blog/photo-tech/color-spaces-page1

Comment: @NSD The exif.cgi clearly displays the Color Encoding: see this: http://regex.info/exif.cgi?dummy=on&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffarm3.static.flickr.com%2F2168%2F3529163109_af24772284_o.jpg

Comment: That's nice. Doesn't change the fact that EXIF data and ICC profiles are two completely different things. You should really read something other than blogs if you want to learn what these terms mean, as photographers and designers are generally some of the most clueless people on the planet when it comes to color management, both in implementation and in practice.

Comment: @NSD The author says that it reads the metadata (which I assume you're going to say isn't good enough?  Or am I wrong?)

Anyway the comment is here: 

http://regex.info/blog/other-writings/online-exif-image-data-viewer#comment-37626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't very well written and it would seem as though you've misunderstood it completely. With the possible exception of device link profiles (which almost nobody uses) you're not very likely to ever encounter any document with more than one ICC profile embedded in it. There is absolutely no way to programmatically determine whether or not the profile that is there is the "correct" one unless its a picture of a color target with known values, and there certainly isn't any way to tell how many conversions an image has gone through.

Actually, I take that back; you will find PDFs with multiple profiles. Just not single images.

Comment: If that's true, than how does your printer read the color profile from something that it's going to print?

Comment: First off, the printer doesn't read anything, the OS does, and then it sends its interpretation of the data to the printer driver. Secondly, I never said there weren't any readable profiles in the image, I said there aren't ever going to be multiple "stacked" profiles in an image the way you were describing.